# Redirection to same page in PHP [but it has different content]

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a simple 4 page application using PHP sessions.  Page 1 asks for username/password, page 2 asks for some information, page 3 displays some results and asks for more info and page 4 is the "success" page.  When they are at page 4 I want them to be able to press my submit button and go back to page 2, retaining the username/password from earlier in the session.  However, all the pages are named sell-books.php.

I tried using

```
<?php
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```

and

```
$_SESSION['next_page'] =  "point";
```

The first just gives an error (I have it as the action for a form in an external file)

and the second does not redirect to the page...the page I want to redirect to is a function named request_point()

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with the session variable, e.g.

```
if ($_SESSION['next_page'] == "point") {
    request_point();
}
```

Comment: I do indeed have that exact line of code in there, it's before all of my functions.

Comment: You haven't really given enough information to answer the question, then. Without seeing more of the logic of your pages, all we can do is guess at what you're doing wrong.